# Unpacking variables from a list with pickle - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, serialization, save, pickle

I am creating a text based RPG with Python 3 and I am using pickle for serialization/saving. What I am trying to do is instead of typing each variable into the dump function of pickle, I have them in a list so that I can save dynamic data later on, such as, if the player chops a tree down in a certain tile of the world, it adds it to the list of things to save next time the player saves. The dump feature works with the list and a for loop like this

```
    def save(self):
    save = input("What would you like to name the save?(This will overwrite): ")
    y = 0
    for x in self.gsd:
        pickle.dump([x], open("{0}.tin".format(save), "wb"))
```

"self.gsd" is a list for 'general save data'. This is what the list looks like:

```
self.gsd = [self.scwpriv, self.scwvisited, self.wallet[I.goldpiece], self.skillblacksmith, self.skillgunsmith, self.skillfishing, self.skillleatherwork, self.skillbuilding, self.skillmining, self.skillforaging, self.skillhunting, self.skillcooking, self.skillalch, self.xpblacksmith, self.xpblacksmithnext, self.xpbuilding, self.xpbuildingnext, self.xphunting, self.xphuntingnext, self.xpcooking, self.xpcookingnext, self.xpfishing, self.xpfishingnext, self.xpforaging, self.xpforagingnext,
                 self.xpmining, self.xpminingnext, self.xpalch, self.xpalchnext, self.xpgunsmith, self.xpgunsmithnext, self.xpforaging, self.xpforagingnext, self.xpleatherwork, self.xpleatherworknext, self.stackinv, self.maxhealth, self.inventory, self.questlog, self.compquests, self.name, self.health, self.xpos, self.ypos, self.rs, self.ms, self.hs, self.cs, self.ps, self.fs, self.damage, self.gundamage, self.shot, self.reloading, self.defence, self.status, self.fighting, self.ammo, self.gold, self.devenabled]
```

When I use dump to save each variable in the list with a for loop, it seems to work. The problem is when I try to use the same method to load it back in with pickle, using another for loop like this:

```
    def loadt(self):
    load = input("What file would you like to load: ")
    for x in self.gsd:
        x = pickle.load(open("{0}.tin".format(load), "rb"))
```

There are no errors, it doesn't crash, however it just plain and simple doesn't load the variables. What am I doing wrong? Can I not use a for loop to unpack the variables with pickle?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Your issue is not clear to me. Note, pickle doesn't load and save *variables* it loads and saves *objects*. Your loading loop will overwrite `x` a local variable each time, leaving `x` as the last object you loaded

Comment: I think OP might be trying to do effectively a `setattr(self, var, val)` in a class using pickle. @shanefales, can you clarify what the intended output is?

Comment: Why don't you just dump the whole list, i.e `self.gsd`?

Comment: If I save and load without the list and the loop, it works fine. I need to use some sort of dynamic storing method for the variables so more can be added later while the player plays the game, but once I use a list and a loop it stops loading them. When I load, it just seems like it did nothing.

Comment: I've also tried that. The saving works, the loading does nothing

Comment: **what does "does nothing" mean exactly**? What did you *expect it to do*? Have you tried `print(x)`? Again, your loop overwrites `x`, so you will only ever have the last object in `x`.  But it doesn't do "nothing". If you dump a list, then load the pickle, you will have that list. What were you *expecting*? Again, you aren't loading and saving *variables*, you are loading and saving *objects*. Your list doesn't contain *variables*, it contains objects. You *need to provide a [mcve]* that shows the issue you are encountering. Saying "this does not work" is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: The question is how to get it to load the OBJECTS then. My basic problem is I want a method to add new variables to save and load when the player introduces something that needs to be saved, for example, chopping down a tree in a certain area. I have hundreds of tiles in the world space, and I only want to have to save the ones the player changes. I thought I could do it with a list, and a loop, which I'm wrong. The question is HOW to do it.

Comment: Your code *does load the objects*. Your `load` function simply doesn't do anything with those objects. **What were you expecting it to do?** Again, *please provide a [mcve]*, or else this questions is off-topic.

Comment: If I remove the list and the loop out of the equation and have them in the load function manually, I.E, self.inventory, self.gold, self.health = pickle.load(open("{0}.tin".format(load), "rb")), it works. What I mean by works, is it sets those values to what was saved. But I need a way to add to that with a function of some kind, for when something in, for example, a tile in the world, is changed. That needs to be saved, and loaded later on when the player loads their save up.

Comment: You need to create some sort of state object that maps the attribute names to the object values. You could just use a `dict`. Again, you seem to fundamentally misunderstand how objects/variables work in Python. `x = pickle.load(open("{0}.tin".format(load), "rb"))` just loads the next object in the pickle and assigns it to the local variable `x`. your list has no idea what attributes the objects you put into it correspond to.

Comment: Or why don't you just serialize the whole tile object?

Comment: Alright, close the question. You don't have to be so condescending about it.

Comment: I'm not being condescending. You are coming here and not providing a [mcve], providing vague problem descriptions, then dismissing the comments that are asking for clarification or trying to tell you where your seem to have a misunderstanding. If you don't want people to ask you for clarification or to suggest that you are understanding incorrectly, then why post a question on StackOverflow? EDIT: Note, after all these comments *you still haven't provided an MCVE*. You haven't even edited your original question.

Comment: I second pickling the whole list. You could try using `*args` to unpack the list after you've loaded it back in. Pickle does *not* save the names, as those are quite irrelevant from a processing standpoint